# Background Android Service is running but not doing anything after the process is killed

Tags: android, android-service, android-backup-service, android-background

I have registered a Service that runs in background.
It runs fine when main process is also running. However, if the process is killed or app is swiped off from recent, I can still see that the Service is running in background under 'Settings -> Apps -> Running Apps'. 
The problem is that though the service is running, it ain't doing anything.

Any idea on why this is happening? Any info on how to make this right?

Comment: Please retrurn START_NOT_STICKY in onStartCommand in service

Comment: What that service is supposed to do? Is it sending some Status bar notifications ? What made you think that service ain't doing anything?

Comment: Actually, the service must be killed with `stopService(Intent);` for started service or `unBindService();` for bound service. It's your responsibility to stop them. If you want to make the service is completely stop when Android system kills it, you have to return `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()` method.

Comment: I have used START_NOT_STICKY once and START_STICKY once but both cases, it didn't work @james

Comment: The Service supposed to change wallpaper when an e-mail is received by phone. It works as long as the process is running. The moment I swipe it out, it  doesn't. However, I see that the service is still running. @AADTechnical

Comment: @Android_Noob Do one thing in onDestroy stop the service.

Comment: @Android_Noob Can u show us code.